# Yii2 searching form from 2 fields is not working

Tags: yii2

I tried to do searching form from 2 fields. But i can't. Help me please
[image from siteController and site/index](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DZpt4.jpg)

> code from siteController

```
        public function actionDriver(){

        $driver = new Driver();

        $journey1 = Driver::findOne(['from' => $this -> from]);
        $journey2 = Driver::findOne(['to' => $this -> to]);

        if($journey1 -> id == $journey2 -> id){

            $driver = $journey1;
            return $this->render('site/index',['driver'=>$driver,
            ]);
        }
    }
```

> code from site/index

```
<?php
    use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;
    use yii\helpers\Html;
    ?>
    <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([
                'action' => ['index'],
                'method' => 'get',
            ]); ?>

            <?= $form->field($driver, 'from') ?>

            <?= $form->field($driver, 'to') ?>

            <div class="form-group">
                <?= Html::submitButton('Search', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
            </div>

            <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

Comment: explain better .. you need.. and post the code   not an  image ..

Comment: If i understand right .. you ask for two fields (from and to) and and if the two fields have the same id you want show in site/index the first model (driver1) right?

Comment: yeah, i have table in db with fields like id.. , from , to ... and i just want to organize searching form from two fields in one row

Comment: I have posted an answer .. hope is useful

Answer (score 0):

findOne if for pk use you should use find -> where and check if you load somethings or nothings

```
  public function actionDriver(){

    $driver = new Driver();

    if ( $driver->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {

        $journey1 = Driver::find()->where(['from' => $driver->from])->one();
        $journey2 = Driver::find()->where(['to' => $driver-> to])->one();

        if($journey1 -> id == $journey2 -> id){

           $driver = $journey1;
        }
    } 
    return $this->render('site/index',['driver'=>$driver,]);
  }
```

Comment: thanks but i have another mistake  Getting unknown property: app\controllers\SiteController::from

Comment: the var $this in cotroller is referred to control itself and not to the post value  .. for obtain the post value you can use Yii::$app->request->post(); .. i have update the answer ..

Comment: Trying to get property of non-object  and it shows   $journey1 = Driver::find()->where(['from' => $post->from])->one();

Comment: again "Trying to get property of non-object" but in this time it shows if($journey1 -> id == $journey2 -> id){

Comment: the view form shows correctly, but it's not working. even if i input correct  data It shows nothing. i wrote condition else.  if($journey1 -> id == $journey2 -> id){ $driver = $journey1;  return $this->render('driver',['driver' => $driver,]);  }  } else return 'Not found'; and it shows Not found but i have  this data in db table

Comment: how can i unite the search conditions ==>> $journey1 = Driver::find()->where(['from' => $driver->from])->one();
            $journey2 = Driver::find()->where(['to' => $driver-> to])->one(); in one condition i think it's not working because here two conditions

Comment: I don't understand the logic you want implement  i . have correctly solve you coding problem .. so ,, in SO this  answer should do ..if the code work ..i think that my work is done and my answer should be rated . properly ..

Comment: ok i understood,I just wanted to this searching form is working. Thanks a lot  for your help